# Convert object to json in angular 7

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to convert an object to json using:

```
object.json();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
core.js:15713 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
```

I think it's some change from the new version. Version 7

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Not enough information, please provide code snippets [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

[The `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

`JSON.stringify(object)`